# OTRS installation errors on openSUSE

Tags: installation, timeout, gateway, opensuse, otrs

I have a fresh, text-only installation of openSuSe 13.1 (physical server, old Samsung netbook), and I'm trying to get OTRS up and running. I've installed OTRS using the below commands. I don't think they're all necessary, but someone in the OtterHub forums had a successful installation with the software versions I'm targeting using this sequence, so I was trying to piggyback on that success.

```
zypper in otrs-3.3.4-01.noarch.rpm gcc make mysql-community-server perl-Crypt-SSLeay perl-JSON-XS perl-YAML-LibYAML
zypper in perl-Text-CSV_XS perl-PDF-API2 perl-GDGraph perl-Encode-HanExtra postfix perl-DBD-mysql
cd ~otrs && bin/otrs.SetPermissions.pl --otrs-user=otrs --web-user=wwwrun --otrs-group=www --web-group=www /opt/otrs
rcmysql start
systemctl start apache2.service
mysqladmin --user=root password password
```

All of that works fine. I'm able to get to the OTRS web installer, but that's where I get hung up.  I get to the part of the web installer that creates the database, and it times out. The script successfully creates the database and updates `Config.pm` with the new password. I can't tell from `installer.pl` what it tries to do next.

Here's the error from `/var/log/apache2/error_log`:

```
[Tue Jan 28 20:53:23.136306 2014] [cgi:warn] [pid 6856] [client 192.168.1.10:52732] AH01220: Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/installer.pl, referer: http://svr-clptest/otrs/installer.pl
[Tue Jan 28 20:53:23.136470 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 6856] [client 192.168.1.10:52732] Script timed out before returning headers: installer.pl, referer: http://svr-clptest/otrs/installer.pl
```

The browser displays the following:

```
The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.
```

This is on a local network at home. I'm accessing the Linux server using PuTTY from a Windows 8 machine. I'm using a wireless connection from the Windows 8 machine, but the server has a hard line connection to the router, if that makes any difference. I don't have any trouble executing anything from PuTTY or accessing the index page through the browser (Firefox 26). I've tried connecting from a computer on my network, and one off of my network. In both cases, I'm able to get to my domain and the web installer. But I can't make a PuTTY connection to the server from outside my network.

I've spent a couple of hours researching the error, and I can't figure out what the next step should be.

Right now, a text-only version of openSUSE and OTRS are the only things running on the machine. I haven't done anything else with it. I'm open to starting the installation from scratch again--OS and all. I'm thinking that the timeout error has something to do with my firewall settings, but I'm not a network guy. Really have no idea how to diagnose this.

**UPDATE**

I tried reinstalling everything fresh tonight, but then added KDE so I could walk through the web installer on the host. I get exactly the same errors. It's not a problem between server and client. Something's wrong with OTRS... I think. Or maybe something's not configured right in apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not exactly sure what the error was with the web installer, but I was able to overcome the problem by deleting the existing OTRS database and following the instructions for manual database configuration found in the OTRS admin guide (http://doc.otrs.org/3.0/en/html/manual-installation-of-otrs.html). After doing the manual configuration, setting up the cron jobs, and restarting the otrs service, I was able to log into localhost/otrs/index.pl using the default root credentials. Still not sure what was wrong with the web installer, but everything is up and running now.